# Finding the ring of integers and integral basis of 2 cubic fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

"Let $L_{1} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^3-18\alpha-6=0$

and $L_{2} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^3-36\alpha-78=0$

(i) Prove $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are cubic fields

(ii) Prove that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ is an integral basis of $O_{K_1}$, resp. $O_{K_2}$, so $O_{K_1} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, $O_{K_2} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$"

So part (i) is pretty simple, by showing that the polynomials $X^3-18X-6$ (for $L_{1}$) and $X^3-36X-78$ (for $L_{2}$) are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then we know the degree of the field extension is $3$ in both cases, so both are cubic fields. To prove this, I used Eisenstein's Criterion with primes $2$ and $3$

For part (ii), what I have is:

We know $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ form a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$. I've considered the discriminant of both polynomials, getting $22356=2^{2}.3^{5}.23$ and $10692=2^{2}.3^{5}.11$. Even though these are not squarefree, as 2 and 3 fulfil the Eisenstein's Criterion for both polynomials, we only have to consider $23$ and $11$, which are squarefree, so $O_{K_1} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, $O_{K_2} = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and so $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ is an integral basis of $O_{K_1}$ and $O_{K_2}$

Am I missing anything? I'm most confused by what it means by '$1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ is an integral basis of $O_{K_1}$, resp. $O_{K_2}$'

Comment: $2,3$ are Eisenstein, so what ? The non-$2,3$ part of the discriminant is square-free, so what ? It means $O_K=\Bbb{Z+\alpha Z+\alpha^2 Z}$ ie. $\Bbb{Z[\alpha]}$ is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: I have proof of the fact that if $f(x)$ is an eisenstein polynomial for some prime p, then p does not divide $[O_{K}:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]]$ where $f(\alpha)=0$, and so we do not need to consider them when looking at the determinant. We then also know that if the determinant is squarefree, then we have found an integral basis of K, and so an integral basis of $O_{K}$. I ask about what resp. means? It doesn't make an sense to me to say it that way

Comment: There is no such thing as integral basis of $K$. All we want is to find $O_K$, the smallest Dedekind domain (unique factorization and invertible prime ideals) such that $Frac(R)=K$. I don't know any direct proof for the Eisenstein prime part, to me the idea is that Eisenstein at $2$ implies $(\alpha,2)^3 = (2)$ ie. the prime ideal above $2$ is invertible.